# javascript search using indexOf doesn't work with map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Trying to hide and show a list using react but fail

```
handleChange = e => {
    const { list } = this.state;

    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      this.setState({
        list: list.map(o => ({
          name: o.name,
          hide: !o.name.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1
        }))
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        list: list.map(o => ({
          name: o.name,
          hide: false
        }))
      });
    }
  };
```

Any clue what's wrong? https://codesandbox.io/s/8ljkoz41k2

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain you what you did wrong

`hide: !o.name.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1`

In above code, indexOf value will be returned (might be some number) which will then return **false** because of `!` operator.

You are trying to compare a **BOOL** value with an Integer **-1** which will obviously return **false**

Wrap your condition with Brackets and put `!` as follows,

`hide: !(o.name.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1)`

Or use the below condition,

`hide: o.name.indexOf(e.target.value) === -1`

It will work.